How to always get updated data from the database?
I have an NET Core API 2.1 and I need to select data from database for my report page.
The data is updating by other applications and I need to read always updated data from db.
But I couldn't force EF to always get updated data from database. How can I do?
Repository.cs
 protected readonly OracleDbContext _dbContext;

 public MyRepository(OracleDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

public async Task<List<Holiday>> GetSuppressedEventsAsync(){
   List<Holiday> list = _dbContext.Holidays.FromSql(OracleScripts.selectSql).ToList();
   .
   .
   return list; // it returns old data    
}

OracleDbContext.cs
public class OracleDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        public OracleDbContext()
        {

        }

        public OracleDbContext(DbContextOptions<OracleDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        
         public DbSet<Holidays> Holidays { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }

    }


Why do you assume DbContext doesn't return the latest visible data? Are you sure you aren't seeing the effects of Oracle's Multiversion concurrency model, where readers see the original copy of the data if a writer is modifying it? You'd get the same behavior if you used any database IDE and executed raw SQL.

The only reason to see unexpected cached objects is serious misuse of EF Core by eg using fake "repositories". EF doesn't need to be wrapped in CRUD classes, it's an ORM loading or persisting entire graphs of application entities at a time. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a multi-entity Unit-of-Work tracking all the application entities in a specific use case, and therefore required to be short-lived. That's why it's registered as Scoped, never Singleton. If the application code registers MyRepository or OracleDbContext  as singletons, it completely breaks EF's concurrency model

In any case, you need to post enough code to replicate the problem. EF doesn't return stale data. How is MyRepository used, where does it get OracleDbContext from and how are both registered with the dependency injection middleware? What kind of application are you building? Desktop? ASP.NET Core? Blazor? It matters, especially in this case. In ASP.NET Core the lifetime (scope) of a scoped service is a single request. In Blazor Server it's (roughly) the entire user session.

Firstly, used properly there is very few use cases for using FromSql() Holidays can and should be fetched using:
List<Holiday> list = _dbContext.Holidays.ToList();

... where any applicable filtering is done via Linq expressions. For example if you have an IsActive flag that you want to default to only return active records:
List<Holiday> list = _dbContext.Holidays
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)  
    .ToList();

... etc.
Where it comes down to getting stale date from the DbContext, this can most often be due to receiving tracked instances that were loaded at an earlier point. This can be a symptom of a DbContext instance being alive too long (DbContexts should be short-lived) or simply not seeing updates you expect to be done concurrently by another user/DbContext instance. (Such as when working multi-threaded which requires a DbContext instance per thread.)
To ensure you are reading current data there are a couple of options. Firstly you can use non-tracking queries:
List<Holiday> list = _dbContext.Holidays
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();

This ensures that the entities read come from the database and not any tracking cache. The entities read also do not get added to the tracking cache. This is good for read operations, but won't work for updates unless you Attach the entities, which can cause issues if the DbContext does happen to be tracking another reference to the same row(s).
You can also dump the tracking cache using:
 _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();

This is a bit of an atomic bomb solution as it will remove all tracking references, so if that instance has any modifications or references to entities you intend to update, those tracking references will be removed. Any existing entity references will not be affected, just changes to those entities will not be tracked by the DbContext nor sent to the DB if you call SaveChanges.
Ultimately the thing to check would be the lifespan of the DbContext instance you are using. For web applications the DbContext lifetime should be no longer than the life of the request being processed. For Desktop applications it may be tempting or easy to overlook a DbContext that is left alive over the entire life of the application run. This is a very bad practice as the tracking cache will continue to serve stale data that doesn't reflect external changes to the data, and the more entities that the tracking cache tracks, the slower the operations to read and update entities will get as it searches through a growing cache of entities to check.  Make sure that any DbContext instances you use are kept alive only as long as they are needed for an operation to complete. Basically think of it that for an operation there should be one, and only one call to SaveChanges, and that the DbContext would be disposed pretty much immediately after that occurs. DbContext instances are cheap/fast to construct, (beyond the very first instance which incurs a static setup cost to resolve all of the mappings) so avoid the temptation to treat it like a Singleton.

I tried to using AsNoTracking but it doesn't get updated data. Ehen I try to add _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear() it gives ''ChangeTracker' does not contain a definition for 'Clear'' error. because my version is 2.1.  And also I need to use '.FromSql' for our complex sql, could this be the reason? @Steve Py

Check that your DbContext's connection string at runtime to make sure it is pointing at the correct database, you will have to Google how to do that for your particular EF Core version as it has changed a few times. Also check that any SQL statement you are executing isn't including a USE statement or such that might point at a different database than what you expect. I would strongly recommend updating the project to at least EF Core 6 as EF Core 2.1 was never really what I'd consider production ready and is long out of support.
